# I need to create a program that promts the user for the name of two input files to be read. It then read in the files and display statistics

Tags: c

This is the code that I currently have but it doesn't seem to compile. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main (void)
{
  FILE *textfile1;
  FILE *textfile2;

  int c;
  char Filename;

  printf("Enter the name of text file:");
  scanf("%s", &Filename;

  textfile1 = fopen(textfile1, "r");
  if (textfile1 == NULL)
  {
    printf("File not found");
  }
  else
  {
    while (fscanf(textfile1, "%c", &textfile1) == 1)
   {
     printf("%c", textfile1);
    }
    fclose(textfile1);
    }
   }
```

Comment: What's the matter with what you have?  Is it not working in some way?  Please elaborate.

Comment: The will not compile, it has 2 errors. One is missing type specifier - int assumed. Note:C++ does not support default-int. Second error is 'FILE' *fopen(const char *,char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from FILE *' to 'const char*'

Comment: `scanf("%s", &Filename;` is missing a `)`

Comment: Besides the obvious syntax error you have, please tell us what's wrong with the program. Does it give build errors? Run-time error or crashes? Produce the wrong results or output? You may want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So you are actually programming in C++, and not C? Then you should edit your question to set the correct language tag. Also include the actual, complete and unedited errors in the question body.

Comment: Sorry if i have posted the question wrong, i'm knew to the site, just need a little help. I cant add the errors in the question as i am on a different pc that what the code is on

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) /* you had better specify the return value explicitly */
{
 FILE *textfile1;
 FILE *textfile2;

 int c;
 char Filename[1024]; /* allocate enough buffer to store the name */
 char textfiledata1; /* add this to store the data from file */

 printf("Enter the name of text file:");
 scanf("%1023s", Filename); /* add ), and other change including limit of length to read to avoid buffer overrun */

 textfile1 = fopen(Filename, "r"); /* you have to pass the name. Do not pass the uninitialized file pointer! */
 if (textfile1 == NULL)
 {
  printf("File not found");
 }
 else
 {
  while (fscanf(textfile1, "%c", &textfiledata1) == 1) /* store the data from file to the file pointer? nonsense. */
  {
   printf("%c", textfiledata1);
  }
  fclose(textfile1);
 }
 return 0; /* explicitly return something is a good practice */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This might be a silly question but can i ask why you have put the number 1023 in with the %s

Comment: To limit the length to read to 1023 (1024 - 1 for terminating null character) in order to reduce risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: Ok thank you. When I go to run this code and enter the file name, an error message pops up saying 'project1 has stopped working' is this an error with my code or the program not working

Comment: Fmmmm... This code works well on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EK81kUx23K9Qyzwg).

Comment: Okay never mind, Thank you for your help. Im using visual studio 2015 btw